# How to change img src without ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone know about how to change image source without have any id in img element?

For Example :

```
<div id="first-div-id">
     <div class="div2">
          <div class="div3">
               <div class="div4">
                   <img src="old-img.jpg">
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

i like to change img inside 4th div, but there is no any id on it.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#first-div-id .div4 img').src = 'new-image.png'`

Comment: You could just do `#first-div-id img` and skip the rest of the children assuming this is the only case and ids aren't reused

Comment: You could add this script document.querySelector('#first-div-id .div2 .div3 .div4 img').src = 'new-img.jpg';